# file_exists() failing without safe_mode being on

Tags: php

```
        spl_autoload_register(function ($className) 
        {
            if (file_exists($className . '.php'))
            {
                require_once($className . '.php');
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception('Could not load class: ' . $className);
            }
        });

        //Load models and save them in variable instances
        try 
        {
            $this->database = new Database  (
                                                $config['DB']['HOST_IP'], 
                                                $config['DB']['DATABASE_NAME'], 
                                                $config['DB']['USERNAME'], 
                                                $config['DB']['PASSWORD']
                                            );
            //Set the initial language for our template model.
            Template::setLanguage();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Script works if I erase `file_exists`, but `file_exists` returns false no matter what.

What may be causing this?

Also, I get an error message: `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not load class: Template'`. Is it because Template class is static?

Comment: `file_exists()` searches actual filesystem paths, but not `include_path`. So are you passing a path that can be accessed on the filesystem, like a relative path to the current script?

Comment: If this is the case, there are a few examples [on the `file_exists()` docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) on wrapping it to search `include_path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was having two extensions on my PHP file. (e.g index.php.php) Sadly, the windows environment wasn't configured so I struggled finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 faults with your code.

1. Instead of meaningful and reasonable system error message you are ecoing just useless and generalized error message which cannot help you
2. You uare using `try-catch` just to echo a message. Which is deadly wrong.

So, just get rid of all try-catch blocks in your code and run it again.
And never use `try..catch` if you're not going to *handle* an error

instead of that set error reporting to be able to see the error messages

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Comment: Error reporting is already set to same on development environment. Isn't require_once failing is exception worthy? I'll appreciate if you can show the correct way. Ps. Did you get my e-mail I sent you yesterday?